# Does not show the view AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, routes, electron

I try to show a view with angular paths. the console does not throw any error or warning.

But equally the view is not displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head></head>
    <body>

        <ng-view></ng-view>

        <!-- build:js bower/vendor -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <script src="./routes.js"></script>

        <!-- build:app scripts/js || CUSTOMER -->
        <script src="./components/customer/customerService.js"></script>
        <script src="./components/customer/customerController.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild-->

    </body>
</html>
```

routes.js

```
var _templateBase = './components';

angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: _templateBase + '/customer/customer.html' ,
            controller: 'customerController',
            controllerAs: '_ctrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });
    }
]);
```

costomerService.js

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .factory('customerService', function() {

        });
```

costomerController.js

```
angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('customerController', ['$scope', function($scope, customerService) {
      //
    }]);
```

It's wrong? Because the view is not displayed? I'm using obsolete mertodos, guide me lleguar many tutorials there.

Thanks so they can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates your app because you have included the second parameter (an array of dependencies to inject):

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
])
```

Remove the second parameter on your other `angular.module()` definitions because that is causing a new app to be created each time.

```
angular.module('app') <-- no second parameter tells it to use the existing 'app' module 
    .factory('customerService', function() {

    });

angular.module('app') <-- no second parameter tells it to use the existing 'app' module
    .controller('customerController', ['$scope', 'customerService', function($scope, customerService) {
      //
    }]);
```

I added `customerService` to your injection array on your controller definition because the array elements have to match up exactly to your function parameters. 
Also, if you are using `controllerAs` syntax as you have done on your route definition then you may not want to inject `$scope` into your controller.